# Using of OperaDriver for Selenium WebDriver

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, opera

I can't launch my tests with OperaDriver. I used operadriver-1.5.jar ; operadriver-v0.18.zip ; operadriver-v1.1.zip and many others from here:
 https://github.com/operasoftware/operadriver/downloads

I use for Selenium Webdriver  selenium-server-standalone-2.33.0.jar .

Example of code:

```
import org.junit.*; 
import org.openqa.selenium.*;
import com.opera.core.systems.OperaDriver;
import com.opera.core.systems.*;

public class Opera_test {
private WebDriver operadriver;
private String baseUrl;

 @Before
 public void setUp() throws Exception {
 operadriver = new OperaDriver();
  baseUrl = "http://www.google.com";
  operadriver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
  }
@Test
public void testCaseGoogle() throws Exception {
  operadriver.get(baseUrl + "/");

 }

 @After
 public void tearDown() throws Exception {
 operadriver.quit();
 }
```

I got an error after that:

## #

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/openqa/selenium/interactions/Keyboard
    at Opera_test.setUp(Opera_test.java:23)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:45)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:42)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:27)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:30)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:263)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:68)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:47)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:231)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:60)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:229)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:50)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:222)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:300)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
        Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.openqa.selenium.interactions.Keyboard
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    ... 25 more
```

##

How is it possible to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I've seen this kind of error when the driver version and browser wasn't compatible. So try to upgrade your Selenium, current version is 2.35 (I suppose you keep your browser up-to-date so this could help).

Comment: I started my tests with 
**selenium-server-standalone-2.35.0.jar** and for OperaDriver **operadriver-v1.1.zip** .
I use browser Opera Version/11.62 and i have the same error.

Answer (score 0):

The following java code should work. I used Selenium WebDriver 2.53.0

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.opera.driver", "D:/SeleniumCode_Ripon/operadriver_win64/operadriver.exe");
driver = new OperaDriver();
```

Answer (score 0):

If U use newest version of opera, You should use [operachromiumdriver](https://github.com/operasoftware/operachromiumdriver)

If U want older version of opera, then older opera driver. So it all depends on your Opera version.